# Is it possible in Win10 to have a path which shows the content from multiple folders?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, junction, windows-libraries

I have a program (call it App1) which read data from `c:\ProgramData\ProgramCompanyName\App1\`

I need to get the content of `ProgramCompanyName` on another disk, so I moved that folder to `D:\App1\ProgramCompanyName\` and made a symlink in `c:\ProgramData\`, and all works flawlessy.

Now I have another program, App2, which reads data from `c:\ProgramData\ProgramCompanyName\App2\`, and again I still need to keep the content of `ProgramCompanyName` on another disk (so no, I can't just symlink `App1` and `App2` in `c:\ProgramData\ProgramCompanyName`).

So, in the end, i want to have:

```
dir D:\App1\ /S
   ProgramCompanyName\file1-1
   ProgramCompanyName\file1-2
   ProgramCompanyName\App1\file1-3
   ProgramCompanyName\App1\file1-4

dir D:\App2\ /S
   ProgramCompanyName\file2-1
   ProgramCompanyName\file2-2
   ProgramCompanyName\App2\file2-3
   ProgramCompanyName\App2\file2-4

dir c:\ProgramData\ProgramCompanyName /S
   file1-1
   file1-2
   file2-1
   file2-2
   App1\file1-3
   App1\file1-4
   App2\file2-3
   App2\file2-4
```

There's a way to "join" ("merge"? I don't even know the terminology) two folders (`D:\App1\ProgramCompanyName\` and `D:\App2\ProgramCompanyName\`) to access them as if they are a single one?

I know about Windows Libraries but (AFAIK) a library does not have a path.

Comment: Please see [this](https://serverfault.com/a/480369/343843) answer on ServerFault. While it's possible this feature may exist in Windows in the decade since that answer, it's unlikely.  [Hard linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) _(PowerShell: [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.4))_ multiple files into a single file is possible, but not with directories AFAIK

Comment: Would creating the folder   `C:\ProgramData\ProgramCompanyName`, along with the subfolders `App1` and `App2`, and then populating those with SymbolicLinks to the files on ` D:\  ` do the trick?

Comment: @KeithMiller: nope, as I should manually mantain the links to deleted files and to the new ones.

Comment: You mean the file names change frequently frequently and the frequency and/or number of files makes manually deleting/creating corresponding links or impossible, that could be scripted...